# "Unable to generate the derived image located at public://styles/uc_category/public/tg.jpg"

Tags: 7, files

(Drupal 7 under Linux)

This is clearly a Drupal permissions problem, but I'm baffled. If I

```
rm -rf styles
```

and refresh the page causing the error, styles and it's sub-dirs are re-created thus:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 25 16:07 styles

drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 25 16:07 uc_category

drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 25 16:07 public
```

But I still get the error. And I *still* get it if I

```
chmod -R 777 styles
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332697/unable-to-generate-the-derived-image-using-image-style-url

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure this is not a permission issue, also make sure you have a graphical library installed on your server.

In D7, the configuration page for this is: /admin/config/media/image-toolkit